# Make multiple user types access the same Route using Laravel 9 middleware

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-9, laravel-middleware

I followed this [site](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-9-multi-auth-create-multiple-authentication-in-laravelexample.html) on how to create user types and restrict page access. Everything works as expected, but I wanted the admin to also have access to the users pages.
The app has several hierarchical levels and I don't want to have to repeat the same Route several times, how can I do that?

Im using this: (short version)

**routes/web.php**

```php
...
Route::middleware(['auth', 'user-access:usr'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('pages.activityHome');
    });
});

Route::middleware(['auth', 'user-access:adm'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('activity/{id}/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\activityController::class, 'editActivity'])->name('edit.activity');
});
```

**Models/User.php**

```php
...
protected function type(): Attribute
    {
        return new Attribute(
            get: fn ($value) =>  ["usr", "adm"][(int) $value],
        );
    }
```

**Http/Middleware/UserAccess.php**

```php
...
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $userType)
    {
        if(auth()->user()->type == $userType){
            return $next($request);
        }
          
        // return response()->view('errors.check-permission'); 
    }
```

**Http/Kernel.php**

```php
...
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'user-access' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserAccess::class,
    ];
```

This way the adm doesn't have access to /, but he should, how can I do it?

I tried how to place more elements in the array and put several groups separated by a comma, but it doesn't work.

Like this: `['auth', 'user-access:usr', 'user-access:adm']`, `['auth', 'user-access:usr,adm']`

Comment: you can pass more than 1 parameter to a middleware

Comment: I tryed this: `Route::middleware(['auth', 'user-access:usr'], ['auth', 'user-access:adm'])`, but dont work

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different way and it worked.

**Http/Middleware/UserAccess.php**

```php
...
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $userType)
{
    if(in_array(auth()->user()->type, explode('.', $userType))){
        return $next($request);
    }

    return response()->json(['You do not have permission to access for this page.']);
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```php
...
Route::middleware(['auth', 'user-access:usr.adm'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('pages.activityHome');
    });
});
```

I'm basically checking to see if any of the user types are in the array.

Comment: middleware are designed to allow multiple parameters ... signature: `handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$userTypes)`  check array: `in_array(auth()->user()->type, $userTypes)` .... then `user-acess:usr,admin` for the middleware on the route